# What is the most efficient way to update the childNodes of a DOM node with an array of DOM nodes, with the minimum number of DOM mutations?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, dom

Let’s say I have a DOM node `parent` which may or may not have child nodes. If I have an array which contains child DOM nodes, some of which may already be a child of `parent`, what is the best way to set the `parent`’s children with this new array such that the minimum number of DOM mutations occur? We identify nodes which are already in the parent by simple referential identity (`===`), and we remove nodes which aren’t found in the new children. Existing children can be reordered as well.

Note that simply setting childNodes of parent to the array doesn’t do anything, but is essentially what I want to do:

```
// doesn’t do anything
parent.childNodes = children;
```

Here’s what I have so far:

```
function updateDOMChildren(el, children = []) {
    if (el.childNodes.length === 0) {
        const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (let child of children) {
            if (typeof child === "string") {
                child = document.createTextNode(child);
            }

            fragment.appendChild(child);
        }

        el.appendChild(fragment);
        return;
    }

    let oldChild = el.firstChild;
    for (const newChild of children) {
        if (oldChild === null) {
            el.appendChild(
                typeof newChild === "string"
                    ? document.createTextNode(newChild)
                    : newChild,
            );
        } else if (typeof newChild === "string") {
            if (oldChild.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                if (oldChild.nodeValue !== newChild) {
                    oldChild.nodeValue = newChild;
                }

                oldChild = oldChild.nextSibling;
            } else {
                el.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(newChild), oldChild);
            }
        } else if (oldChild !== newChild) {
            el.insertBefore(newChild, oldChild);
        } else {
            oldChild = oldChild.nextSibling;
        }
    }

    while (oldChild !== null) {
        const nextSibling = oldChild.nextSibling;
        el.removeChild(oldChild);
        oldChild = nextSibling;
    }
}
```

This solution is suboptimal in the case where nodes are removed in the middle, because the later nodes are inserted before the to-be-removed nodes, even though they don’t have to be touched. For instance:

```
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span><!--removed-->
  <span>3</span><!--removed-->
  <span>4</span>
</div>
```

```
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>4</span>
</div>
```

In this transformation according to my current algorithm, the `<span>4</span>` node is inserted before the `<span>2</span>` node before the `<span>2</span>` node is removed. Is there a way to tweak the algorithm so this extra insertion does not happen?

Alternatively, is there a more efficient algorithm for implementing this function? Is there a more generic name for this algorithm (updating a linked list with an array)?

Comment: Unless you're adding thousands of nodes, modern browsers are extremely efficient in dealing with DOM modifications.

Comment: @Pointy I understand that; I’m mainly asking to see if there is a better algorithm to use, and if there is a name for the algorithm. In addition, the unnecessarily moved DOM nodes are sometimes producing surprising results when I attempt to test things via MutationObservers.

Comment: @brainkim It seems like you are looking for algorithmic solutions to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-to-string_correction_problem, computing some minimal delta/diff. However I am pretty certain that just going through the list of new elements, (re)appending them and removing the other nodes will be more performant than computing the optimal edit sequence.

Comment: @Bergi I’m not sure edit distance algorithms apply here because elements are unique with children and persist even if they’re moved around to different positions, whereas edit distance algorithms work on symbols which can be repeated/are interchangeable. Maybe this is a special-case of an edit distance problem? I agree that it might be faster just to stick with what I have rather than trying to calculate the most optimal edit to childNodes.

Comment: @brainkim It seems that you were comparing strings/text nodes by their value, not by their identity though. But you're right, it is a bit different - I doubt that makes it simpler though. Consider e.g. https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43668/14663